# PySpark - loop through each row of dataframe and run a hive query

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with 100  rows [ name, age, date, hour] . I need to partition this dataframe with distinct values of date. Let's say there are 20 distinct date values in these 100 rows , then i need to spawn up 20 parallel hive queries where each hive QL will join each of these partitions with a hive table . Hive table  - [dept, couse , date] is partitioned by date field.

Hive table is huge and hence I need to optimize these joins in to multiple smaller joins and then aggregate these results. Any recommendations on how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Could you provide sample data, with the expected output? You should consider doing only one join and broadcasting your 100 row dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in single query. Partition both df on date and join. During join broadcast you first table which have small data (~10MB). Here is example:-

```
df3 = df1.repartition("date").join(
F.broadcast(df2.repartition("date")), 
"date"
)
#df2 is your dataframe smaller dataframe in your case it is name, age, date, ,hour.
#Now perform any operation on df3
```